# Multiple Macs for iOS development

Tags: ios

relativly newb here so be easy please...

I have an iMac, a MBP and a new Mac mini with the provisioning profiles on all devices. What I am looking for is information on if there is an automatic way to save my current code changes that were made on the iMac so that when I use the MBP off site I can use the lateset code without having to copy everything to a USB stick and physically transfer it? Dropbox works OK but it is not automatic.

Comment: Look into Git repositories.

Comment: I actually like both answers and I will investigate both as time permits and decide on which way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just setup an account with github, setup all the computers to pull from your github account and then just make sure you are actively pulling and committing to github. This is easily done with source control.

How To Use Git Source Control with Xcode in iOS 6
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox actually is automatic. Just put your project in a Dropbox, and it will sync it across all your Macs.

I also recommend considering using a source control system, for example [git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics). You can set up a free repo at GitHub.com or BitBucket.org. All the real software shops use source control. It gives you a lot of power and flexibility with tracking changes and managing versions of the code. There is a learning curve however.